# Getting an error when running ansible script - "Unicode object has no attribute "site_name"

Tags: ansible

I'm currently running an ansible galaxy project that I have created.  What I am trying to do is take one of the attributes on the variable and set it to a path name.  I have created a file inside of group vars called `websiteNames` and inside of that file I have a variable that is set up like this -

```
my_websites:

  - site_name: website2
    site_url: website2.com

  - site_name: website1
    site_url: website1.com
```

My ansible file that calls it is set up like this -

```
- name: deploy public vhosts /etc/httpd/conf.d
  template:  
    src: ../../websites/files/vhost.conf 
    dest: "/etc/httpd/conf.d/{{ item.site_name }}-public.conf" 
    owner: root 
    group: root 
    mode: 0644
  with_items: my_websites
```

However, when I am trying to run the actual playbook, I get the following error - `FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'unicode object' has no attribute 'site_name'"}`

If it is helpful, here is the part of the template file where I call the variable -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/{{ site_name }}/stuff
    ServerName {{ site_name }}
```

Do I need to call the group cars `websiteNames` file at some point?  It seems like it is not recognizing the group_var has been added.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give the full path of your `websiteNames` file. And keep in mind that `with_items: my_websites` syntax is deprecated, you should use `with_items: "{{my_websites}}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue that I was having was that the group I was calling in the host file was called "myServers", but the name of the group_var was my_servers.  I did not realize that the group var had to have the same name as the original host variable.